# how do i put a $variable inside {curly..brackets} in a bash loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

i'm writing a text art script where i take some input and repeat it, textbook simple.

```
echo "a script that takes some input and repeats it 100 times"
read -e -p "text input " inputtext

for n in {1..100};
  do echo -n "$inputtext"
done
```

this works well, but how would i go about adding a read input to the `for n in {1..100}` part?

`for n in {1..'$repeats'}` doesn't work for sure..

i'm very new to bash scripting.

how do i put variables inside curly brackets in a bash loop?